# How do I write instances of the different typical Java classes?

Tags: java, class, types

Apologies for the confusing title. I am not experienced with Java so I lack the right terminology. Basically, I am trying to create a map between Java types (i.e. `Class`) and JDBC types (as strings). So I am trying to make something like this:

```
private static final Map<Class, String> javaToJdbcTypeMap;
static
{
    javaToJdbcTypeMap = new HashMap<Class, String>();
    javaToJdbcTypeMap.put(String, "varchar");
    javaToJdbcTypeMap.put(Integer, "int");
    //etc for other common Java types
}
```

However, String and Integer are giving me problems. Intellij tells me "Expression Expected". Instead of `String` I tried `"".getClass()`, and it works, but I feel like that's horrible style and that there should be a straightforward way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Mapping of JDBC Types to Java Types](https://db.apache.org/ojb/docu/guides/jdbc-types.html#Mapping+of+JDBC+Types+to+Java+Types) should help. Also you add ".class" to get the class like `javaToJdbcTypeMap.put(String.class, "varchar");` And, since Java 7, you might use the [Diamond Operator `<>`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java#Diamond_operator) like

```
javaToJdbcTypeMap = new HashMap<>();
javaToJdbcTypeMap.put(String.class, "varchar");
javaToJdbcTypeMap.put(Integer.class, "int");
```

Comment: Ah right, that's what I wanted. I knew it was something obvious. And thank you for the link -- it's the reference I'm using right now :)

Comment: @Drew There are [other mappings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/mapping.html), and you can implement what you need if you can't find an existing mapping.

Comment: Cheers, I'm actually working with Amazon Redshift and since they focus on data warehouse optimizations they support quite a [limited amount of datatypes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Supported_data_types.html), so I should be fine -- thanks!